# Complex numbers modulus inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, contest-math

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$. Prove that $|az + b\bar{z}| \leq 1$, for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $|z| = 1$, if and only if $|a| + |b| \leq 1$.

I want to know if my demonstration is correct.
Here is how I did it:

From $|z| = 1$, we have $|z|^2 = 1$, which is equivalent with $z \cdot \bar{z} = 1$.

$z \cdot \bar{z} = 1 \Rightarrow |z| \cdot |\bar{z}| = 1 \Rightarrow |\bar{z}| = \frac{1}{|z|} = 1$

$|az + b\bar{z}| \leq |az| + |b\bar{z}| = |a| \cdot |z| + |b| \cdot |\bar{z}| = |a| + |b|$.

And from here we have the conclusion that $|az + b\bar{z}| \leq 1$, ( $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $|z| = 1$ ), if and only if $|a| + |b| \leq 1$.

Comment: I see only one direction (the if, not the only if).

Answer (score 1):

Compute $|az+b\bar{z}|^2$, and $(|a|+|b|)^2$, compare the expressions and see it this suggests an approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have proven correctly that $|a|+|b|\le 1 \Rightarrow |az+b\bar z|\le 1$.

Good!

That leaves proving that $|az+b\bar z|\le 1 \Rightarrow |a|+|b|\le 1$.

To do so, I suggest picking a $z$ such that |a+b| takes it maximum value. Hint: convert to a polar expression.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you only one direction. For the other direction, take:

$$ z = \sqrt{||\frac{a}{b}|| \times \frac{b}{a}}$$

Demonstration:

Put $a = r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $b = r_2e^{i\theta_2}$. Of course $r_1, r_2 > 0$.

We have that:

$$||\frac{a}{b}||\frac{b}{a} = \frac{r_1}{r_2}\frac{r_2e^{i\theta_2}}{r_1e^{i\theta_1}} = e^{i(\theta_2 - \theta_1)} $$ So that:

$$z = e^{\frac{i(\theta_2 \ - \ \theta_1)}{2}}$$

Now:

$$||az + b\bar z|| = \ ... \ = ||r_1 + r_2|| = || \ ||a|| + ||b|| \ || = ||a|| + ||b||$$

Thus: $||a|| + ||b|| \le 1$